# PHP Included File Breaking Site - How can I grab a variable from the included file without including the whole script to my site?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, geocode

I'm running a site on WordPress. I've included a local PHP script that connects to a local Geocode database and finds out the users' location. It works fine, even when I include it into my site (I can pull the variables I need), but it seems to stop the rest of the site from loading. As if I "required" a file that didn't exist. I'm not sure why this happens, especially since I can still echo the variable before the site breaks.

Is there a way to make this script run and pass me the variable I need without including the entire script into the site? Maybe have it run in the background somehow? Your guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Erm, are you including remote script? Scary stuff... The code may look harmless now, but...

Comment: No it's a local script. It's the PHP API from MaxMind.com's GeoCode database.

Comment: And I know which file is breaking the site: geoip.inc. I just can't figure out why. I can post all the code here but it's long, about 500 lines.

Comment: Ok then, your wording threw me off :) Are you sure this isn't just a `require` vs. `require_once` issue? Offloading with something like `gearman` can always be done, but I doubt it's necessary here.

Comment: Well I replaced all the require_once's to include. It didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Getting any Errors or Notices? Turn on `error_reporting` if it's not.

Comment: Error reporting is on, I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: I've been at this for a couple hours already. The script works fine when it stands alone. When I include it into WordPress, it still works fine, but the site breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use curl to get the content safely and then parse it for the data you need.  If you include it directly you are vulnerable to a number of security attacks and the execution of your script could stop like it is now.

Comment: Thanks but sorry for the confusion; I'm not trying to include an external script. It's local. It just seems to break my WordPress site when I try to include it.

Comment: then just open the file and read its contents.  include will execute the file in the scope of the script that included it which is dangerous.  You can then parse the results and scope any variable you like with the value.